# Лишний отступ в блоке. media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Адаптирую сайт под мобильные устройства.

Лишний отступ появляется  на `@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}`
**Cсылка http://portfolio.esy.es**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Вы о каком отступе говорите? Слева от email?похоже у Вас там место для номеров телефонов. Просто на Вашем скрине их нет, а место они занимают.... Кстати, у меня телефоны появляются. Почему на Вашем скрине их нет?

Comment: Исправил фото, я дебажу через mozilla, так что когда я тяну туда-сюда размер экрана бывает не показывает нормально media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уменьшите ширину этого элемента:

```
<a href="#">Видеогалерея</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Там вообще страшное дело с этими absolute.